# Spring cloud stream cannot pass comma separated properties during deployment

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to migrate scdf version from 1.7.3 to 2.1.2

While deploying a stream with the older version, I was able to provide named input destination during stream deployment (using Dashboard UI) as follows:-

app..spring.cloud.bindings.input.destination=input1,input2.

After upgrading to SCDF 2.1.2, I am not able to do the same. SCDF throws an error which states "Invalid Character ',' found in the deployment properties.

I tried to pass these properties as array elements as follows:

app..spring.cloud.bindings.input.destination[0]=input1
app..spring.cloud.bindings.input.destination[1]=input2

This does not work either.

End Goal is to be able to bind two different output destinations that belong to two different apps to a common input destination of the app .

Comment: Hi. Can you share the stream definition in entirety, please? It'd also help if you can share a snippet of your custom application, so we can reason through as to how you're expecting to receive the data in the consumer application.

Comment: Also, if you're upgrading, please switch to the latest 2.2 GA release.